# Click event not working on child elements added dynamically

Tags: jquery

I've the [this page](http://preview.inhaltlaufenredner.strafrecht-online.org/falltraining/step-2/#/falltraining/klausuren/bierdurst/). You can highlight different areas of text on the page using the different markers mentioned on the right side of the page.

Whenever you mark an area, a `span` is added with the class of the marker. So suppose if you use the yellow marker from the right. The highlighted area will be covered using the following span tag. `<span class="mark1">[ highlighted text ]</span>`.

What I want to do is simply whenever a user clicks this span tag I want to change it's border. But somehow I am unable to achieve this.

Here's what I am trying to do.

```
$("#sachverhalt").find("span").on("click","span[class='mark1'],span[class='mark2'],span[class='mark3'],span[class='mark4'],span[class='mark5']",function(){
    $(this).css('border',"1px solid #000000");
});
```

**EDIT:**

And the tag structure looks like this.

```
<div id="sachverhalt">
 <article>
   <p>
     <span>
       [some random text]
       <span class="mark1">
         [highlighted text]
       </span>
       [some random text]
     </span>
   </p>
 </article>
</div>
```

Where the `<span class='mark1'><span>` tag is added dynamically when the user highlights it.

Can anyone please tell me why this event is not being called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use $(document).on(event, selector, function)
Otherwise the event handler will not be bound to the new elements.

That should also work with: (remove find("span"))

```
$("#sachverhalt").on("click","span[class='mark1'],span[class='mark2'],span[class='mark3'],span[class='mark4'],span[class='mark5']",function(){
    $(this).css('border',"1px solid #000000");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: the problem is if I used `$(document)` than this functionality will work on the markers also shown on the right side of the page since they have the same tag and class name. this is why I am using `$('#sachverhalt')` so that the elements in it only have the click event assigned. DO you get what i mean ?

Comment: It will work with $("#sachverhalt").on("click", ...);
But don't filter on existing spans before .on()

Answer (score 0):

When elements are added to the DOM after the page has loaded, you need to bind the even to an element that existed when the DOM loaded. So to make you click work, bind to the listener to the body.

```
$("body #sachverhalt").find("span").on("click","span[class='mark1'],span[class='mark2'],span[class='mark3'],span[class='mark4'],span[class='mark5']",function(){
    $(this).css('border',"1px solid #000000");
});
```